# How do I move a text file I exported from app data to a place outside the app's sandbox using Swift/SwiftUI in iOS?

Tags: ios, file, directory, icloud, sandbox

I have an app that normally stores data for the user. All works fine but I want to give the user the chance to export the data to a CSV and do as they wish with it.

Right now, I have the CSVs but they sit inside the app's sandbox and are very difficult and unfriendly for the user.  How can I move these to a place outside the app sandbox to a place that the user is more familiar with like their Documents folder in iCloud or their Downloads folder?

SwiftUI solution would be great but Swift works too!

I have no code to show since I'm completely stumped.

Comment: There is no SwiftUI component. You can use an instance of [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) to let the user export the file to somewhere convenient, such as the files app or a cloud storage location such as Dropbox.

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay, I can wrap the UIDocumentPickerViewController with a representable. Thanks!  BTW ... is that Tandy Model 2 in your pic?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Paulw11 for the direction! I was quite uncertain how to go about it but it's brilliantly simple!

As I created the export files, I saved the URLs into an array. I then passed them to a struct I made using UIDocumentPickerViewController implementing UIViewControllerRepresentable (for SwiftUI).

The struct looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct DocumentPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var URLs: [URL]
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) ->
        UIDocumentPickerViewController {

        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(urls: URLs, in: .moveToService)
        return picker
}

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>){}
}
```

You end up with all your files ready to be moved to a location chosen by the user:

[image: Modal window presented to allow user to choose a save-to location!]